# EarlyStopping keras with consecutively epoch

Tags: keras

I used early stopping in keras with 
early_stopping = kr.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', 
                patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto')
However, I got the result as below:

[image]

The val_loss at epoch=2 is 0.6683, val of epoch=3 > 0.6683, but the training begun to work and the val begun to decrease from epoch 3. When I set patience=10, I would like the training will stop with 10 consecutively epochs with no improvement, not only compare epoch 2 and epoch 12 like that. Could someone know how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: I fixed, just modified the earlystop of keras:

Answer (score 1):

I fixed, just modified keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping:

Replaced

```py
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    ...
    if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best):
        self.best = current
        self.wait = 0
    else:
        self.wait += 1
        if self.wait >= self.patience:
            self.stopped_epoch = epoch
            self.model.stop_training = True
    ...
```

by

```py
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    ...
    if epoch == 1:
        self.previous=logs.get(self.monitor)

    #if val_loss of current < previous, set wait=0
    #if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best):

    if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.previous):
        # if current < self.previous:       
        self.wait = 0
    else: #if val_loss of current > previous, that means performance pause improving, then set wait+=1
        self.wait += 1
        print 'now: ' +str(current) + ', pre: ' +str(self.previous) + 'not improved! wait:' +  str(self.wait)
        if self.wait >= self.patience: #if wait reach limitation, then stopping training
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True      
    if epoch > 1:
            self.previous=logs.get(self.monitor)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own callback according to the [Keras Documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/). What you would want to do in your case is to edit the `on_epoch_end()` method from the Keras version of EarlyStopping. Instead of keeping track of the best value, you want to keep track of the previous value and see if it doesn't improve for 10 consecutive times.